# Не работает клавиатура Devil may cry 4 в Wine

Tags: linux, ubuntu, wine

Так получилось, что я захотел установить пиратку Devil may cry 4. Устанавливал по этому [гайду](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5RD8H1Exrnk). Версия WINE "System", потому что в остальных версиях не работал установщик, а сама игра работает на всех имеющихся у меня версиях(3.0.3, 1.7.22-d3dforce и System). Я установил Devil may cry 4 special edition и просто Devil may cry 4. Везде одна и таже проблема — не работает клавиатура, кроме клавиш по типу пробела и ctrl. В чём может быть проблема и как её исправить? На сайте есть подобный вопрос, но мне не помог ответ оттуда. Если на linux есть программа эмулирующая геймпад, то подскажите, я проверю работоспособность геймпада.

Answer (score 1):

Решение нашлось! Проблема в раскладке клавиатуры, которую надо менять через терминал вот этой командой:        setxkbmap us